# Like a pig in a wig

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Aunt Petunia often said that Dudley looked like a baby angel — Harry
> often said that Dudley looked **like a pig in a wig.**

My research : I guess this is a dated idiom as well and means "someone is trying to look better than he really is".

Though does it mean that or it mean literally.
As in he was like pig (fat) in a wig (blonde hair)?
Or does it mean he was fat but used to wear really nice clothes?

Comment: ***wig*** does not imply *blonde*.

Comment: The idea of this quotation from a Harry picture is to characterise two people, 'Aunt Petunia', who is gushing and uncritical, and Harry, who is grumpy and sour (and probably envious.  If you say aloud what Petunia says, you will hear how she ends with open vowels "baaby aangel". And the consonants in "aangel" and liquid"  But 'pig' and ' 'wig' are short and stumpy and grudging.  And of course a pig in a wig would look silly and stupid.

Comment: You may be overthinking this! It's a children's book. Children might picture a pig wearing a wig, and giggle. That's probably what the author would like them to do. Of course, if you say someone looks like a pig, you are saying they are ugly. By the way, the rhyme is old. Like fish/dish, bell/well, day/play and hundreds of others, it probably first appeared in a children's song, a folk song or a nursery rhyme.

Comment: @Tuffy: Ah! Research! I didn't bother with that :-) +1

Comment: @Jim but Miss Piggy (the muppets) is blonde...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Right, but I don’t think this is a reference to Miss Piggy *per se*.

Comment: @Jim Maybe, maybe not. But if I think of "mutton dressed up as lamb" I think of a woman who looks like a blonde Barbie in her late 40s or 50s. ugh..

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I guess I took it much more literally. Dudley is a fat pig but with hair. And the only way to get a head of hair on a pig is via a wig.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest Google Books match for "pig in a wig" is from "[Precocious Piggy](https://books.google.com/books?id=VxUTAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22pig+in+a+wig%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwialJyakM3zAhW1JzQIHTgMBnEQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22pig%20in%20a%20wig%22&f=false)," in *Home Songs for Little Darlings* (1859):

> Where are you going to, you little pig? / "I'm going to the barber's to buy me a wig." /  A wig little pig! / A pig in a wig ! / Why, who ever before saw a pig in a wig?

The expression does not seem to be proverbial. In fact, the "pig in a wig" verse of the poem follows previous verses involving rhymes with *big* ("so young, so big!", *dig* ("a little pig dig!"), *gig* ("a pig in a gig!"), *swig* ("a pig have a swig!"), *jig* ("a pig dance a jig!"), and *rig* ("a pig run a rig!"), and preceding a verse involving a rhyme with *twig* ("hop the twig!"). The only surprise is that the little pig doesn't also dry a fig and vote for a Whig.

As Old Brixtonian notes in a comment beneath the posted question, children's rhymes often present nonsense juxtapositions purely on the basis of their involving two rhyming nouns. Dr. Seuss's [*Fox in Socks*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qV6KDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Fox+in+Sox%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipltS6nc3zAhX3HLkGHZdUCDQQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a relatively recent example of this phenomenon, but I imagine that it goes back centuries. A [thumbnail review of Fritz Eichenberg, *Ape in a Cape: An Alphabet of Odd Animals*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yg5GAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pig+in+a+wig%22&dq=%22pig+in+a+wig%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitoeDSk83zAhXyppUCHd1XCUM4FBDoAXoECAQQAg) in *Quarterly Bulletin: Books for Children* (1955) offers additional several examples:

> A skilled artist represents each letter of the alphabet by a bold and lively drawing of an animal with a brief rhyming caption, such as "mouse in a blouse, **pig in a wig**, toad on the road, whale in a gale.

Although these nonsense verse references to a pig in a wig refer literally to a pig wearing or planning to buy a wig, the expression has been used figuratively (and insultingly) in instances that antedate the one in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. For example, from Eden Phillipotts, [*Ghostwater*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iUQ1AAAAMAAJ&q=%22pig+in+a+wig%22&dq=%22pig+in+a+wig%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0uJ38lc3zAhWBJ7kGHRh2B484KBDoAXoECAMQAg) (1941) [combined snippets]:

> I listened to every minute of the trial and if I'd guessed you were going to lose, I'd have come to you a lot sooner; but I never did guess it. The other chap—that fat **pig in a wig** that worked to hang Lamb—was out to beat you if he could. He weren't there for truth, nor justice, nor anything like that. He wanted to score off you. He didn't care two pence for Lamb's life and he worked like hell to block you and make you look foolish. But the dishonest blighter knew how to get round the jury all right. He appealed to their heads and you appealed to their hearts , and you could see the clash in their chapfallen mugs when they brought in their verdict and tagged the plea for mercy to to it, because they wanted to run with the hare and hunt with the hounds. Like we all do for that matter. ...

In this instance, the wig is literal, but the pig wearing it is the prosecuting barrister.

In *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, the comment that "Harry often said that Dudley looked like a pig in a wig" indicates first that Dudley was quite overweight and in other respects (such as greediness and selfishness) piggish, and second that his haircut—presumably featuring long curly locks in the Little Lord Fauntleroy tradition (se the [cover illustration in this edition of that book](https://books.google.com/books?id=N8LtBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT57&dq=%22Little+Lord+Fauntleroy%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO37WCm83zAhVBFjQIHeZHAssQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Little%20Lord%20Fauntleroy%22&f=false))—looked unflatteringly absurd when juxtaposed with his face and physique.

Comment: Could you add this answer to the duplicate question rather than here?

Comment: @DJClayworth: I actually don't think the questions are the same. To "feel like a pig in a wig" is to experience a certain emotional awkwardness; to "look like a pig in a wig" is to have a certain appearance. There is some overlap, certainly, in the issue of whether "pig in a wig" is proverbial or idiomatic or neither; and I do spend most of my answer addressing that question. Nevertheless, I don't think my answer is transferable to the earlier claimed duplicate, if only because it makes no attempt to answer the question "What does the phrase 'I feel like a pig in a wig' mean?"

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is an insult to someone who has tried to improve their appearance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).